# Issue with the logic determining cache hits and cache miss in CacheAspectSupport Spring

Tags: spring, spring-cache

```
@Caching(cacheable =
    {
        @Cacheable(cacheManager = "localCacheManager"),
        @Cacheable(cacheManager = "redisCacheManager"),
    }
)
```

I can implement a memory hierarchy using `@Caching` as shown in the code above. However, the problem is that the criterion for a cache hit in `CacheAspectSupport` is when at least one of the `@Cacheable`'s is a cache hit. Conversely, a cache miss is determined when all `@Cacheable`'s are cache misses.

The code below is part of the `execute` method of the `CacheAspectSupport` class, which relates to the aforementioned issue.

```
// Check if we have a cached item matching the conditions
Cache.ValueWrapper cacheHit = findCachedItem(contexts.get(CacheableOperation.class));

// Collect puts from any @Cacheable miss, if no cached item is found
List<CachePutRequest> cachePutRequests = new ArrayList<>();
if (cacheHit == null) {
    collectPutRequests(contexts.get(CacheableOperation.class),
      CacheOperationExpressionEvaluator.NO_RESULT, cachePutRequests);
}
```

For example, let's think about a case where a certain key is a miss in the first cache but a hit in the second cache. This key will always result in a hit in the second cache unless it's cached in the first cache. Since it's a hit in the second cache, it ultimately results in a cache hit. The problem here is that there's no way to synchronize the first and second caches due to the ultimate cache hit.

What I want to do is to synchronize the cached value of the first cache, where the miss occurred, with the second cache when a hit occurs in the second cache. However, I currently don't have a good method to do this. Can you suggest a good solution